# Imported CocoaPod SwiftRSS still causes 'undeclared type of RSSFeed'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I use the SwiftRSS pod for a simple iOS RSS feed reader. 
The pod has been installed successfully and I opened the workspace file.

I was able to write `import SwiftRSS` and build it without any errors.
But if I try to use any classes of the pod, I'll always get the well-known error message like 'Use of Undeclared type RSSFeed'.

The class is nevertheless 'clickable' and shows me the code-behind file.

Thanks for your help.